# Recursion in Python vs. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function in JavaScript. I can write it in Python with the following code:

```python
import copy
kamers1 = [[0,0],[0]]
lijst = ['a','b','c']
uitkomst = []

def fill(kamers, mens):
    counter1 = 0
    for i in kamers:
        counter2 = 0
        for j in i:
            if j==0:
                kamers[counter1][counter2] = mens
                return kamers
            counter2+=1
        counter1+=1
    return False

def main(kamers, mensen):
    if mensen == []:
        uitkomst.append(kamers)

    for i in mensen:
        temp_mensen = copy.deepcopy(mensen)
        temp_mensen.remove(i)
        temp_kamers = fill(copy.deepcopy(kamers),i)
        main(temp_kamers, temp_mensen)
main(kamers,lijst)
print uitkomst
```

Which will give me the expected answer:

```
'[[['a', 'b'], ['c']], [['a', 'c'], ['b']], [['b', 'a'], ['c']], [['b', 'c'], ['a']], [['c', 'a'], ['b']], [['c', 'b'], ['a']]]'
```

I'm currently in the process of learning JavaScript, so I wanted to write this code in it. This is what I made:

```js
var lijst;
// Definieer een lijst met daarin de kenmerken van de persoon
lijst = [   {naam: "a", 'vriendje': 'b'},
    {naam: "b", 'vriendje': 'c'},
    {naam: "c", 'vriendje': 'b'}
];

var uitkomst = [];

var kamers1;
// Definieer een lijst van kamers die we moeten vullen met mensen
// Bij deze kamers is het dus duidelijk de bedoeling dat b & c in de eerste kamer komen
// Hierdoor zal de overall happiness het hoogste zijn!
kamers1 = [[0,0],[0]];

function fill(kamers, mens){
// Vul de eerste plaats in de kamers op met een mens
for (i=0; i<kamers.length; i++){
    var temp_kamer = kamers[i];
    for (j=0; j<temp_kamer.length; j++){
        if (temp_kamer[j]==0){
            kamers[i][j] = mens;
            return kamers
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}

function testen(kamers){
    // Vul de eerste plaats in de kamers op met een mens
    for (i=0; i<kamers.length; i++){
        var temp_kamer = kamers[i];
        for (j=0; j<temp_kamer.length; j++){
            if (temp_kamer[j]==0){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
        return 0;
    }


function main(kamers,mensen){
    // Dit is een recursieve functie die alle mogelijke kamerbezettingen probeert te maken
    var test = testen(kamers);
    if (test == 0){
        uitkomst.push(kamers);
        return 'true';
    }
    for(i=0; i<mensen.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        var temp_mensen = mensen.slice();
        var temp_kamers = kamers.slice();
        var mens = temp_mensen.splice(i, 1);
        temp_kamers = fill(temp_kamers, mens);
        var a = main(temp_kamers,temp_mensen);
    }
    return 'tru';
}

function append(lijst1,lijst){
    // Voeg elementen toe aan een lijst
    for (i=0;i<lijst1.length;i++){
        lijst.push(lijst1[i]);
    }
    return lijst;

main(kamers1,lijst);
console.log(uitkomst);
```

Now this doesn't give me the answer I was hoping for:

```
[[[[Object { naam="a", vriendje="b"}], [Object { naam="b", vriendje="c"}]], [[Object { naam="c", vriendje="b"}]]]]
```

...is the only thing it will spit out. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why does your JavaScript version have objects, where your Python version doesn't? Where's the Python equivalent of `lijst`?

Comment: I quickly wrote the python version to check if I was doing something fundamentally wrong with the recursion. Python equivalent of lijst is mensen. (The idea is that the program gives me all the different combinations possible, with Objects inside so that later on I can calculate a number that represents how good the combination is.)